# Geoserver not starting - after power failure - what is the cause?

Tags: java, tomcat, geoserver

Below is the error part of log , please help to restart it.

```
    01 Jan 10:30:26 WARN [support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'geoServerLoader': java.lang.NullPointerException
01 Jan 10:30:26 ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gwcFacade' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.8.3.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DiskQuotaMonitor' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DiskQuotaMonitor' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.8.3.jar!/geowebcache-diskquota-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DiskQuotaStoreProvider' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DiskQuotaStoreProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.8.3.jar!/geowebcache-diskquota-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception. The usual fix for this is to increase the amount of heap assigned to the JVM using a parameter like `-Xmx756M` in the startup script. See [this page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html) for more details depending on your system.